# Static value in for loop

Tags: java, static

Please don't mind the title couldn't think of a better one. Please edit it if you have any suggestions. I am trying to figure out what's going on here. So let's say I have a class `test.java`

```
class test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
            new Testing().run();
        }
    }
}
```

And the `Testing.java` class

```
class Testing{
    private static String str = "";
    public void run(){
        if(str.equals("")){
            str = "ten";
        }else{
            str = "five";
        }
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

So every time for loop runs and when the Testing object is being created shouldn't it re-assign the static string value to `""` and print `ten` ?
The output I am getting is

```
ten
five
five
five
five
five
five
five
```

Shouldn't the output be `ten` all the time because of new Testing object and reassigning the static string value ?

Comment: After the first loop, `str` isn't blank, so it gets set to `"five"`. What are you imagining would cause it to be reset?

Comment: Remove the `static` keyword from the declaration of `str` and see the difference.

Comment: *shouldn't it re-assign the static string value to ""*: no, since the variable is `static`, and is thus not bound to the instances of the class, but to the class itself. The variable is initialized once to an empty string, when the class (not the objects) is initialized. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Answer (score 2):

No because you used a static variable.
A static variable is common to all the instances (or objects) of the class because it is a class level variable. In other words you can say that only a single copy of static variable is created and shared among all the instances of the class. Memory allocation for such variables only happens once when the class is loaded in the memory.
https://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/static-variable/

when you create an object it holds the value ""
 When you call run str will hold ten as you can see the value printed. 
After the first iteration as str doesn't hold "" it will change its value to five.

Any object that you create will hold the same value for str.